# cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'XXX' is a 'let' constant

Tags: swift

i am new to swift .i am  trying  with several way but i failed when try as suggest error then anther error occur . what is going on exactly here i don't know

```
  public struct ThermometerStruct {
          var temperature: Double = 0.0
      public mutating func registerTemperature(temperature: Double) {
        self.temperature = temperature
      }
    }

    let thermometerStruct = ThermometerStruct()
    thermometerStruct.registerTemperature(temperature : 56.0)
```

> ERROR at line 14, col 5: cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'thermometerStruct' is a 'let' constant
>       thermometerStruct.registerTemperature(temperature : 56.0)
>       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   
>   
>   INFO at line 13, col 5: change 'let' to 'var' to make it mutable
>       let thermometerStruct = ThermometerStruct()
>       ^~~
>       var

Comment: What error do you get when changing `let` to `var`?

Comment: Since `struct`s are _value_ types in Swift, any mutation of any member property of a struct instance means the mutation of the instance itself. Hence to mutate its members, you'd need to follow Hamish's advice and change the `thermometerStruct` instance from an immutable (`let`) to a mutable (`var`) variable. If `ThermometerStruct` were to be a `class` instead, you could mark the `ThermometerClass` instance as immutable (`let`), but could still mutate mutable member properties of it, as `class` types are _reference_ types in Swift.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error-message already tells you, what you need to change. Replace `let` with `var`.

---

`struct`s ar value types. This means, if any property of a `struct` is modified, the instance needs to be declared as `var`.

When your `struct` has a method, that is modifying one of the struct's properties, this method is `mutable`. `mutable` methods can only be called on instances you have declared as `var`.

Comment: thanks i only accept this question  for this line "When your `struct` has a method, that is modifying one of the struct's properties, this method is `mutable`. `mutable` methods can only be called on instances you have declared as `var`."

Answer (score 6):

In case you're using `lazy` var in `struct`s and you're passing it to a function or having a `let` refference of the object, accessing the `lazy var` is implicitly `mutating` to the object.

so you need make a `var` out of it.

```
struct Test {
  lazy var a: String = ""
}
```

...

```
func something(test: Test) {
    let a = test.a //throws compile error

    var test = test
    let a = test.a //OK
}
```